# Como descobrir uma collation de uma tabela ou banco usando uma query SQL?

Tags: mysql, collation

Eu consigo visualizar a collation de determinada tabela ou banco perfeitamente pelo PHPMyAdmin.

Mas se eu não me dispusesse dessa ferramenta supracitada, como eu poderia fazer para descobrir a collation fazendo uma SQL query manualmente?

Answer (score 7):

Basta isso:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE nomedatabela
```

E da base de dados:

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE Syntax
```

A saída é algo assim:

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s` char(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
                              --^^^^^^-- Aqui é o Charset padrão.
```

Se alguma coluna foi definida com um *charset* diferente, também aparecerá no `SHOW CREATE`.

Mais detalhes no manual:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html

Answer (score 6):

Pode listar o collation de cada tabela de uma determinada tabela usando o [information_schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html), da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT table_name, table_collation FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'nome_da_base'
```

Caso precise retornar o collation de cada coluna pode usar essa consulta:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, collation_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'nome_da_tabela'
```